# How do I search over multiple models in a CMS using Sphinx?

Tags: search, content-management-system, full-text-search, sphinx

I'm attempting to using [Sphinx](http://www.sphinxsearch.com) in my CMS as a sitewide search.  Since each model in the CMS has different fulltext fields, I've created an index per model.  However, according to Sphinx's [forum](http://sphinxsearch.com/forum/view.html?id=3504), searching over multiple indexes with different schema is not supported.

How are you CMS guys using Sphinx for your general site search?  Performing a call to Sphinx per model and keeping track of pagination offsets?  Creating one huge index with an index field per model/field?  Is there some other solution I'm not thinking of?

Answer (score 0):

You probably solved this long time ago, but well...

You cannot cover multiple indexes with different Schema in one single call to ->Query(), but **you can execute [multiple queries with AddQuery() and RunQueries()](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#api-func-addquery)**

So, instead of calling

```
->Query( 'keywords' , ( 'schemaA', 'schemaB', 'schemaC' ) )
```

You do:

```
->AddQuery('keywords' , ( 'schemaA') );
->AddQuery('keywords' , ( 'schemaB') );
->AddQuery('keywords' , ( 'schemaC') );
->RunQueries();
```

You will get an array of results, one for each query. Then in your search results page you could display the results separated by 'type' (or schema) like:

___ *RESULTS PAGE* __*_*__*_*_

Searching for "blue"...

--- we found 23 results in cars ----

- car 1
- car 2
- car 3
- ..

--- we found 2 results in houses ----

- house 1
- house 2
- house 3
- ..

_ (end) RESULTS PAGE ***_*__*_*_**